# Adding an index to a table with 130,000 rows causes a FastCGI timeout in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, iis, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to add an index to the `Datetime` field on my `transactions` table.

I'm doing this via PHPMyAdmin, as I don't have SSH access.

Unfortunately, when I attempt this on `transactions`, which currently has ~130,000 rows, I get a FastCGI timeout error.

If I create indexes on smaller tables the problem doesn't happen.

I believe the index **is** added a while after the script has timed out, but the same issue appears to happen with certain `OPTIMIZE` commands too, so I'd really like to have it resolved and get PHPMyAdmin working correctly.

What settings do I need to look at - in IIS, PHPMyAdmin, FastCGI and PHP - to allow PHPMyAdmin to run this request in its entirety?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Dont worry, the browser is getting timed out, wait for some time, and check the SHOW INDEX.... query, you will have the creation of index done

Comment: If you're getting the max_execution_time error here's a totally hacky way to stop it that I dont advise: open phpmyadmin/index.php on the first line under `<?php` add `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: Is there any way of doing that with less-hacky methods Dale, such as php.ini?

Comment: Change max_execution_time in PHP.INI

Comment: I don't use IIS myself but if you were to change the max time in php ini it might have an affect on all your scripts rather than my hacky suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing MySQL Query Browser, free from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

It's been replaced by the new MySQL Workbench software but you can still download it.

You can run your queries in exactly the same way as phpMyAdmin's 'SQL' tab but without the PHP memory or time limits.